# How can I pass JS variable from a jsp page to another?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have something like this in file1.jsp :

```
var var1 =  "a long string of 20.000 caracter";
document.getElementById('urlPop').value = var1;
```

Also in file1.jsp :

```
<form method="POST" name="urlForm" id="urlForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="urlPop" name="urlPop"/>
</form>
```

(When I use firebug, my hidden input is modify by my javascript as well.)

And there is a link who is maked like this :

```
<a href="${url_rapport}" target="_blank" style="position: relative; top: -5px; left:15px;"  onclick="document.getElementById('urlForm').submit();">Rapport PDF</a>
```

My link open a file2.jsp where I make this :

```
<IMAGEPOP><%= request.getParameter("urlPop")%></IMAGEPOP>
```

But it doesn't work, I don't know why... Had I forgot something ??

Thanks for help, will.

**EDIT :**

**I had just test with an insert in my DB and in the file2.jsp "request.getParameter("urlPop")" is equal to null so the problem is here and I don't know how to solve it :/**

Comment: what is the value of ${url_rapport} ? bcz i don't see any relation between your hidden field and this link.

Comment: How do you submit the POST form ? you should have a submit button to send the POST data of your form

Comment: There is a lot of paramater to use on the second jsp page in this who are created by <c:param name="insee">${insee}</c:param> for example

Comment: @Sn0opr I dont want to have a submit button, I want to submit the form when user click on the link with onclick="document.getElementById('urlForm').submit();

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Session variable or cookies to pass that variable from one jsp page to another. you could also use
[Local Storage.](http://github.com/medialize/jQuery-store)

Comment: I have already try something with session var but how can I store the javascript value in session without passing it in the second JSP page ?

Comment: can't you pass it on queryString as GET request?? or just use LocalStorage.

Comment: if you want to save this variable as a session object, create a servlet, pass that variable to that servlet method, create session object, and access that object in other jsp page.

Comment: Nop, I can't use GET cause the strings I want to sent is long of 24000 caracter and I have 4 url to send :P

Comment: All my problem's here, I haven't develop the appli, I just work to improve her (during an intership) and all the code is in the jsp files, the servlets are automatically generated and we can't change or create some ...

Comment: okay, Now for this case you should use js LocalStorage. please look at the link I mentioned above.

Comment: to use LocalStorage use:  //initialize
$.storage = new $.store();

// save a value
$.storage.set( key, value );

// read a value
$.storage.get( key );

// deletes a value
$.storage.del( key );

// delete all values
$.storage.flush();

Comment: Nop it doesn't solve the problem, my var is always in javascript when I uses it and I need to use it in java code of my second page ...

Comment: your variable is in js, you can save it on hidden input type, and get it anywhere from the id of hidden input type.

Comment: I already save it in hidden input tag, but I can't get it back, my "request.getParameter("inputId")" doesn't work, it's equal to null

Comment: "<input type="hidden" id="urlPop" name="urlPop"/>" and "var var1 =  "a long string of 20.000 caracter";
document.getElementById('urlPop').value = var1;" with this, my input have the url value (I can see that with firebug for example)

Comment: for me <%=request.getParameter("xyz");%> is not working but  <%request.getParameter("xyz");%> is working. you may try it

Comment: remove that href tag also.

Comment: I can't remove the href tag, there some data send like this in the url of my page2.jsp, I will tryw without the = sign

Comment: It's solve, I put an input submit on the form directly with an action="${url_rapport} and it works" ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but, I think you forget a "action" with your form.

have you tryed something like that ?

```html
<form method="POST" name="urlForm" id="urlForm" action="file2.jsp ">
    <input type="hidden" id="urlPop" name="urlPop"/>
</form>
```

Comment: And instead of an <a> tag, try to use another one :

<span onclick="document.getElementById('urlForm').submit();">Rapport PDF</span>

Comment: I think this is a secondary problem that is not yet visible; I have the idea that the browser is triggering a regular get request because of the link being clicked. The link might need a 'return false' in the onclick handler to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @Gimbly Where have I to place the return false ? Something like this : onclick="document.getElementById('urlForm').submit(); return false;" ?

Comment: When I place a return false; like I write before, my link dont work it just refersh my actual page.